# Repetably clicking a button inside a web browser vb.net

Tags: vb.net, browser, web

How do i click a button, preform some if statements (if it matches, exit...) else keep looping (clicking the button)...How do i do this within the web browser control?

A normal loop won't work because the web browser executes the statement multiple times before completing and i can't figure out how to make it loop until a condition is met without freezing the program.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the GUI from freezing an Application.DoEvents helps the gui be more responsive in a loop.

I do not believe you can click an input button with the WebBrowser control (maybe with DOM, you could, but I couldn't answer that), however you can change the control's address within the mentioned loop you have.

Comment: I can click the button using `Webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("buttons_ID").InvokeMember("click")` but that's not the problem.

Comment: isn't there an event on WebBrowser you can capture? (with some sort of url verification check) to change flag to continue the loop somehow, (sorry for being vague.. i'm just not sure of the proper event)